# Lua error making 16x16 grid

Tags: lua

The following code gives me the following error:

> attempt to index a nil value

```
    -- Making grid
grid = {}
local i = 1
local ii = 1
mainx, mainy = love.graphics.getDimensions()
while(i<=mainx) do
    if(i%16==0) then
        while(ii<=mainy) do
            if(ii%16==0) then
                grid[i][ii] = nil
            end
            ii = ii + 1
        end
    end
    i = i+1
end
```

I know lua is 1-based, but i dont really know what goes wrong here.

A fix will be gladly appericated :)

NOTE: mainx, mainy should be 800 and 600.

Comment: Ever heard of a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes. But i didnt find it as useful in this case, as the size of the grid is not fully predefined.

Comment: You should create an empty array `grid[i] = {}` before indexing it with `grid[i][ii]`

Comment: Feel free to post that comment in an answer, I would enjoy accepting it.
Thanks!

Comment: @HåvardNygård - You are also initializing `ii` in a wrong place (move it inside the outer loop).  Sorry, I'm too lazy to write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assign `grid[i]` to `{}` before doing `grid[i][ii] = nil`. Second dereferencing `[ii]` fails because `grid[i] == nil`

I refactored your code below a little.

```
-- Making grid
local grid = {}
local mainx, mainy = love.graphics.getDimensions()
for i = 16,mainx,16 do  -- syntax: for i = <start_value>, <max value (included)> [, <step>]
    grid[i] = {};
    for ii = 16,mainy,16 do
        grid[i][ii] = i*ii  -- some value
    end
end
```